# How to allow the user to use the application only for one device at a time in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uuid

I have been searching Google to find a answer to if it is possible to restrict users to login from one device at a time.

Suppose there is a mobile application (iOS application) which allows one user to login from one device at a time. How can this be achieved ?

To solve this problem, I think the first thing is to identify a device. Maybe by its Mac address, but I did not find any way to fetch the Mac address of a device from user request made from a the application as any identifiers which directly identifies the iOS Device is strictly prohibited by Apple Privacy Policy.

So for this I am trying to do the following things:

- Step 1) **first time login**: API param (username, password, uuid) ,,
- Step 2) uuid - will be empty for first login, API will allow login,
  for empty uuid for that user. IMP but only when there is no uuid for
  that user at server.
- Step 3) **after successful login**, hit another API which with param
  uuid for that user. also store uuid at keychain so for next login you
  will have uuid value.--
- Step 4) if user wants to login on other device then for first attempt
  s/he will send empty uuid but server will not allow login through its
  empty uuid as it has uuid value for that user. so you can notify
  admin with this situation. –

For creating custom UUID I am using the following code :

```
let uuid = NSUUID().UUIDString.lowercaseString
print(uuid)
```

I am saving this UUID to my keychain.

So while thinking to apply the above steps I came to a very serious concern

1. Am I following the correct approach?
2. If yes, for example what if an user A logs into the App then logs out , next User B logs in then will it send the same UUID to the server ?
3. What will happen if the User A logs into the app then uninstalls it without logout and User B logs into it by re installing.

**How to manage the UUID in the above scenarios?
It would be really helpful if anyone could share some thoughts about possible solutions. Thanks!**

Comment: What framework are you using for login/auth management, if you even are?

Comment: No framework am using ... just I am passing these parameters through APIs

Comment: Does the app have access to a realtime database of any kind?

Answer (score 1):

you have to use the token approach and you have to manage it from the backend if is there any new login appear the previous token should expire and in app whenever the token expires it should move to the login screen, and to use **UDID** for this purpose it is completely illegal or maybe your app gets reject when you submit it to the app store
thanks.

Comment: but its a UUID which is custom. Apple itself recommends it

Comment: but it lies in personal information and they not allowed to use it

Comment: to solve your problem in a professional manner you have to manage through the token approach

Comment: @saqibkafeela *UUID* is different to the *UDID*. There is no privacy issue with using a UUID. But otherwise, your approach is what I would suggest. Rather than preventing the second login, you allow it and invalidate the first log in.  This addresses the issues that the OP raised around not logging out.

Comment: This answer is correct, you are going to want to have your backend manage this, and invalidate old user tokens for new logins from other devices

Comment: @Paulw11 If I allow the second login after invalidating the first login rather than preventing the second login will it address the issue if user A uninstalls the application without logging out

Comment: Yes, it will.  If you required them to logout of the first device before allowing them to log in to the second and the first device no longer has the app (or they no longer have the first device or it is damaged...) then they would be stuck